# How can I set a theme in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, icons, themes, qt-designer

I design my user interface with Qt Designer and then load the `*.ui` file in Python.

For buttons I want to add Icons from the Breeze theme. In Qt Designer I can add icons via "Set icon From Theme..."

[image]

But this is loading the icon from a different theme. In my Python code I select the theme via.

```
QtGui.QIcon.setThemeName("breeze")
```

And it shows it at runtime as following:

[image]

This is what I want to see in the Qt Designer as well.

**Question: How can I setup Qt Designer to use the icons from the Breeze theme?**

> Versions:
>
> - Qt Creator: 3.5.1 based on Qt 5.5.1
> - Ubuntu: 16.04
> - PySide2: 5.12.3
> - Python: 2.7.12